# href to subdirectory of current url

Tags: html, href

Assume the current url is : `www.my.com/somewhere`.

And I have a `href` link and want it go to : `www.my.com/somewhere/subpage` without writing current url(`www.my.com/somewhere`) in `href`.

Is it possible in pure HTML (not by javascript or server-side things)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2020 - current state of this question:

if the current URL is this www.my.com/somewhere
The shorthand ./subpage or just subpage will navigate to www.my.com/subpage

If the current URL ends in a /, then it will navigate as question is asking.

www.my.com/somewhere is not the same as www.my.com/somewhere/

So how to navigate to subpage from www.my.com/somewhere?
use: somewhere/subpage

Answer (score 1):

No, a relative link is relative to your current *directory* and domain.com/somewhere is a file, while domain.com/somewhere/ is a directory.

Since /somewhere is a file, the current directory becomes '/' and a relative link to 'subpage' becomes a link to 'domain.com/subpage'.

If you used directories for your pages instead of files, then '/somewhere/' would become your current directory. A link to 'subpage/' would now be relative to '/somewhere/' and would open 'www.mydomain.com/somewhere/subpage/'. But this would probably require 'server-side things', and therefor: No, I don't think it's possible to link to a subpage of the current document.

Comment: If you are by chance working with NextJS, make sure to set to true the trailingSlash configuration in next.config.js. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/trailingSlash

Answer (score 0):

I think ./subpage should do the job.

Comment: It will, but the ./ is not needed and therefore best omitted for brevity.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write the relative path in your href, like this:
`<a href='subpage'></a>`

Comment: That link goes to `www.my.com/subpage`. I need to go to subfolder of current url.

Comment: Do you have for some reason specified a `<base href="http://www.my.com/" />` in the `<head>` of your html?

Comment: "That link goes to www.my.com/subpage. I need to go to subfolder of current url"
No it doesn't, if you are already in /somewhere then simply "subpage" will go to "/somewhere/subpage"
This answer is correct yet it's been down-voted. Please amend.

Answer (score -2):

Unless I am misunderstanding you. You should just be able to write href="/subpage".

Comment: That's a absolute link so it goes to `www.my.com/subpage`. I need to go to `www.my.com/somewhere/subpage`.

Comment: If your current directory is www.my.com/somewhere, and you want to go to www.my.com/somewhere/subpage, then what i just put should work. It works on my website, I just checked it. If you are in the www.my.com directory, then you would use href="/somehwere/subpage"